# Can the rearrangement inequality be applied to a convergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I recently learned about the rearrangement inequality and was wondering whether it could be applied to convergent series. With that I mean that if:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_ib_i$$
is a convergent series with $a_1\ge a_2\ldots\ge a_n$ and $b_1>b_2\ldots>b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that for every bijection $\sigma:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_ib_i\ge\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_ib_{\sigma(i)}$$

I was looking at the proof of the inequality at wikipedia and I'm pretty sure there still is an upper bound, since both series are convergent. The rest of the proof also seems to work, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite version of the rearrangement inequality almost tells us that $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{\sigma(i)}$$ for any $n>0$. Because $\sigma$ restricted to $[n] := \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is not necessarily a bijection from $[n]$ to $[n]$, we can't apply the rearrangement inequality directly. But just define $\tau : [n] \to [n]$ by letting $\tau(i) = \sigma(i)$ whenever $\sigma(i) \le n$ and choosing an unused value of $[n]$ for $\tau(i)$ whenever $\sigma(i) > n$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{\tau(i)}$$ by the rearrangement inequality, and $a_i b_{\tau(i)} \ge a_i b_{\sigma(i)}$ for all $i$, giving us the inequality we actually want.

From here, we're done, since if the inequality holds for all partial sums then it holds for the infinite sum as well.